# removeEventListenerで削除するlistenerを識別する内部的な仕組み

Tags: javascript

リスナーの登録は

```
var listener = function(){
  console.log('click')
};
element.addEventListener('click', listener);
```

登録したリスナーを削除するには

```
element.removeEventListener('click', listener);
```

例えば以下のようにlistenerを書き換えてしてremoveEventListenerすると登録されたlistenerは削除されません。

```
var listener = function(){
  console.log('click')
};
element.addEventListener('click', listener);
listener = function(){
  console.log('click')
};
element.removeEventListener('click', listener);
```

このremoveEventListenerでlistenerを引数にして登録されてるlistenerを識別して削除されるのは内部的にどういう仕組みでしょうか？

Comment: 内部を知りませんけど、単に関数オブジェクトとして異なるから(`==`とか`===`で等値性が判定できる)だと思います。実装例として[このページ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) のコード例が参考になると思います。

Comment: 答えていただいてありがとうございます。removeEventListenerの引数の関数オブジェクトが登録されてる関数オブジェクトかどうかどのように判定してるのか知りたかったのです。

Comment: リンク先のコードだと`if (eventListener.object==this && eventListener.type==type && eventListener.listener==listener) {` の部分ですね。`eventListener` は保持している配列の１つです。 `eventListener=eventListeners[counter]`

Comment: BLUEPIXYさんも指摘されてるように関数が比較できるとは思っていませんでした。。。ありがとうございます。

Comment: なれてなくてすみません。回答に投稿しました。いろいろありがとうございました。

Comment: あと、回答のVのマークの部分をクリックすること（この回答で解決）で質問自体を締めることができます。クリックできるようになるまで時間が必要かもしれません。

Comment: なにからなにまでありがとうございます。自分の回答で締めるには48時間後っぽいですね。

Comment: どういたしまして。(^_^)P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。関数同士を比較することできたんですね。。。知らなかったです。

```
var hoge = function(){};
var foo = hoge;
var bar = hoge;
console.log(hoge === bar); // => true
hoge = function(){};
console.log(hoge === bar); // => false
console.log(foo === bar); // => true
```